# CodeIgniter 3 - Unable to display directory conents of assets folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My assets folder is at the top level, like so:

- application
- assets:
- --css
- --images
- --js
- docs
- system

I don't have any problem accessing my assets folder for stylesheets, javascript libraries, or images.

The problem is I can't seem to scan my assets folder. Specifically, I have a sub-folder of assets/images/assets (called assets because it relates to capital assets, not coding assets. Pictures of houses and properties and such). I want to list, in hyperlinks or list form, the files in the images folder.

In my controller, my code to list the contents of my assets folder is this:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$data['map'] = directory_map('../assets/',1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data['map']);
```

I get a blank page. No matter what relative path I give for my folder path (e.g. '../../assets' or '../assets' or '/assets' or even just plain 'assets') i don't get any output, no files, just a blank page.

I don't think there are any errors, because I can precede the output with

```
echo "@@@";
```

...and trail the print_r command with `echo "@@@"', and both echos print out with nothing between them.

Comment: you shouldnt need to add any trailing slahes. Just enter `directory_map('assets/images/assets');`

Comment: Well, heck. It just works...Comment upvoted, @CodeGoodie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the FCPATH directory_map

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$data['map'] = directory_map(FCPATH . 'assets/', 1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data['map']);
```